# Ubuntu doesn't boot past splash screen

Tags: nvidia, intel, boot-repair, acpi

**Ubuntu doesn't boot past splash screen.**

Error output with splash and quit removed form the linux line of grub boot settings:

```
6.7331291 ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve sumbol [\_TZ.ETMD1, AE_NOT_FOUND (20228331 /psargs-330)
6.7332121 ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB. IETM._OSC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20220331/psparse-529)
snd_hda_Intel 0000:01:00.1: Too many BDL entries: buffer=2097152, period=65536
```

System Info:
Ubuntu version: 22.10
Update Frequency: Weekly

Comment: Given we have no idea as to what Ubuntu product, what release, nor what upgrade are involved (*do you upgrade daily? weekly? monthly? or how often as this knowledge with release details allows us to know what possible upgrades are involved; is it a LTS release that recently switched kernel stack? we won't know until we know product/release*). I'd suggest you provide details as to what you're running as currently your details are *unclear*

Comment: version 22.10, updated weekly. It is a basic install for mainly used for steam and other than that web browsing. The Nvidia proprietary driver is installed.

Comment: Fixed the Nvidia errors, now i just get the last two plus       44.3535171 snd_da_Intel 0000:01:00.1: Too many BDL entries: buffer 2097152, period=65536